# Group By and inner join with latest records based on TimeStamp

Tags: sql-server

I have a `History` table as below:

```
ID | GroupCode | Category | TimeStamp
---+-----------+----------+-----------
1  | x         | shoes    | 2016-09-01
2  | y         | blach    | 2016-09-01
```

`History` table gets updated every month and a single entry for each `GroupCode` gets inserted in the table.

I have also a `Current` table which holds the latest position.

Before or after I update the `History` table with the current position I would like to find out whether the `Category` has changed from last month to this month.

I need to compare the last `Category` with the current `Category` and, if it has changed, then flag the `CategoryChanged` in the `Current` table.

`Current` table:

```
ID | GroupCode | Category | CategoryChanged
---+-----------+----------+----------------
1  | x         | shoes    | True       
2  | y         | blah     | False
```

I tried to achieve this with `INNER JOIN` but I am having difficulties to `INNER JOIN` to latest month and year entries in `History` table, but no success.

Comment: can you post query that you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

```
--get highest group code based on timestamp   
 ;with History
    as
    (select top 1 with ties groupcode,category
    from
    history
    order by 
    row_number() over (partition by group code order by timestamp desc) as rownum
    )

--now do a left join with current table
    select 
    ct.ID,
    ct.GroupCode,
    ct.Category,
    case when ct.category=ht.category or ht.category is null then 'False'
         else 'true'
    end as 'changed'
     from
    currenttable ct
    left join
    history ht
    on ht.groupcode=ct.groupcode
```

use below to update ,after checking if your select values are correct..

```
update ct
set ct.category=
 case when ct.category=ht.category or ht.category is null then 'False'
             else 'true'
        end 
         from
        currenttable ct
        left join
        history ht
        on ht.groupcode=ct.groupcode
```

Comment: How do I update the CategoryChanged column with this?

Comment: I don't think this code is going to work for you, the CTE in the first query only selects a single record, it will select the newest record for one particular group at random - so if you have multiple groups to check, it will not work.  The second update query is trying to alter category to either 'true' or 'false'

Comment: @AndrewDeighton:Cte provides me latest category for all the group codes based on timestamp,not by random

Comment: the query has syntax issues. can you please update the query?

Comment: you have to use above update,in place of select after cte

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'select top 1' will give you 1 or zero rows, you won't get the top one for each group you want - unless that's some really tricky bit of SQL I misunderstood - what if you have multiple 'GroupCodes'?

Comment: I'll clarify what I mean by 'random' - say you have multiple groupcodes, all with 1 or more rows - your row_number is calculated for each group, and will have an entry '1' for each group - so you will have multiple occurrences of a row called 1 - these will all be at the TOP, but you only select TOP 1, so you take just one row with row_number 1, out of many - so it could be for any grouping,.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton:that's top 1 with ties and see order by as well

Comment: @TheGameiswar - sure, I misunderstood it then!

Comment: top 1 with ties gives one item per group ,when used with order by like i used

Comment: @TheGameiswar  - I'll have to eat humble pie, that's pretty neat

Answer (score 0):

if you make a CTE where the history records have rown_numbwer for each GroupCode ordered by date descending, then you are interested in rows 1 AND 2, SO YOU CAN THEREFORE join your CTE on GroupCode, and select records 1 and 2, you can the see if category has changed between rows 1 and 2

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupCode ORDER BY TimeStamp Desc) RN FROM History)
    SELECT 
            C1.ID, 
            C1.GroupCode, 
            C1.Category, 
            CASE WHEN C1.Category = C2.Category THEN 
                'false' 
            else 
                'true' 
            end AS CategoryChanged

                FROM CTE C1 
                        JOIN 
                            CTE C2 
                                ON C1.GroupCode = C2.GroupCode 
                                    AND C1.Rn=1 AND C2.RN = 2;
```

if you have null categories, you can avoid with - BTW you will need to learn how to handle NULLs the way you want to handle them - you can't expect people to post on here thinking about NULLs you never mentioned forever!  And happening to realise what you want to do with them for that matter

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupCode ORDER BY TimeStamp Desc) RN FROM History)
    SELECT 
            C1.ID, 
            C1.GroupCode, 
            C1.Category, 
            CASE WHEN C1.Category = C2.Category OR C1.Category IS NULL AND C2.Category IS NULL THEN 
                'false' 
            else 
                'true' 
            end AS CategoryChanged

                FROM CTE C1 
                        JOIN 
                            CTE C2 
                                ON C1.GroupCode = C2.GroupCode 
                                    AND C1.Rn=1 AND C2.RN = 2;
```

Comment: If the category is null in both this returns true?

Comment: you're being a little too demanding here you know, you didn't really make it clear what you would want to do if both names were 'NULL' (or even if that could happen).  Also you only vaguely mentioned that you expected some update to occur - the details of that are not in any way clear as yet.

Comment: I do apologise. Yes you are right. I did rush to put the question instead of taking time to clearly describe what I would like to achieve. I will try to update my question later.

Comment: @akd - that's ok, apology accepted, was being grumpy - I see you have given help here too - I should have checked that!